# What folder must you cd to to use "mysql --max_allowed_packet"?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, wamp, wampserver

I'm trying to upload a file to MySQL via MySQL client and keep getting a "`#2006 - MySQL server has gone away`" error. I looked into it and think it can be fixed by typing "`mysql --max_allowed_packet=10MB`". What folder do I have to cd to in order to use this command? I've looked into it but the folder varies greatly depending on what server is used. As such, I'm using Wampserver 2.5.

Comment: How are you uploading the file to mysql? Are you using command line mysql client?

Comment: I'm using mysql client. I'll add that to my question

Comment: You will also need to make sure the MySQL *server* accepts 10MB packets before trying to send such big packets with the client. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/packet-too-large.html

Comment: + http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/find-file-folder#1TC=windows-7 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Run cmd command
2. Type c: or d: on command prompt. This will be based on your WAMP server installations.
3. Assuming you have installed wamp on D: drive.
4. cd D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql15.1.36\bin
5. D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql15.1.36\bin>mysql.exe -u root